# Red Gate SQL Prompt - auto complete alter statements lose comments

Tags: sql-server-2008, autocomplete, ssms, redgate

Using SQL Prompt 4 (I'm aware there's an upgrade but I'm not responsible for that kind of thing..)

I like the ease of being able to write alter proc *_*_ and have SQL Prompt fill the rest of the statement, bringing up the required procedue/view/whatever.

Unfortunately, any comments in the procedure that would appear if I'd have browsed through the object explorer of management studio and selected 'modify' (or script as..) disappear.

Is there a way of ensuring the comments are included? they also appear in the output of the proc sp_helptext.. these comments are above the initial 'alter proc' statement.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that comments *before* the `ALTER PROC` keywords are not inserted by SQL Prompt when it automatically fills in the stored procedure body after typing `ALTER PROC` manually or using the `ap` snippet.  We are aware of this limitation.

If you are able to use SQL Prompt 5 one day, there is an alternative in that version that can be used as a workaround.  If you press <kbd>F12</kbd> on a stored procedure name in a query (e.g. `EXEC myproc`), then a new query window is opened with the stored procedure scripted as `ALTER` -- this method *does* keep the initial comments, and isn't too many more keystrokes.

Paul Stephenson
SQL Prompt Project Manager
Red Gate Software

Comment: Thank you Paul, something to look forward to if we're upgraded :)